# Mysql query to check the selected row present in an already computed result array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result_array= select * from table where id = 5;
```

I am getting this result_array from another function.
And in my function, I want to filter out the result based on the returned array.

Is something like this

```
select * from table where * IN result_array AND type=type1 ORDER BY timestamp
```

possible?

This query is giving me an error

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause

Comment: User key of result to filter second query. So fetch result, get column id from it then select by this key. You can`t operate with result array in query.

Comment: You must select only one  field in $result_array., Because in your second query contains In clause.. So instead of select * from table where id = 5 you can select , select id from table where id = 5

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like as:

```
 "select * from table where column_name(like user_id) IN (select user_id from table where id = 5) AND type=type1 ORDER BY timestamp"
```

IN always accept an array of values.

For example we have two tables dealers and dealers_login.

We can filter out dealer login details like :

```
  SELECT  * FROM dealer_login WHERE id IN (SELECT dealer_id FROM dealers)
```

Thanks